# Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_type_get_names() Drupal 7.59

Tags: 7, comments

I upgraded my Drupal site to Drupal 7.59 and now the site is down.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_type_get_names() in D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\biobank\modules\comment\comment.module on line 119

List of installed modules:

1. admin_menu
2. autocomplete_deluxe
3. autologout
4. better_exposed_filters
5. bootstrap_fieldgroup
6. chosen
7. conditional_fields
8. ctools
9. date
10. devel
11. empty_front_page
12. entity
13. entityreference
14. entityreference_autocreate
15. exclude_node_title
16. field_collection
17. field_collection_table
18. field_collection_views
19. field_group
20. field_validation
21. jquery_update
22. mass_pwreset
23. module_filter
24. msnf
25. restrict_ip
26. securelogin
27. security_review
28. termcase
29. title
30. token
31. unique_field
32. vefl
33. views
34. views_bootstrap
35. views_data_export
36. webform

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment but I don't see the `Node` module. Its part of the core and should be present(thats where the missing [function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_get_names/7.x) is defined). Verify that the module is present and permissions are set right

Comment: That seems to be a list of contrib modules, none of the core ones (even the required ones) are in it

Comment: Great catch. Didn't notice that.

Comment: in core module folder I have the Node module and can the function seems to be in node.module 

function node_type_get_names() {
  return _node_types_build()->names;
}

@kombogdan: what permissions should the core module folder or node module folder should have?

Comment: Probably something like 750 on directory for apache user and 640 on the files. Also have you tired to run 'drush cc all' in site's folder?